# Can I get a Georgia visa on gcc residence permit?

Tags: georgia-country, visas-on-arrival

I am resident of Saudi Arabia, holding a Pakistani passport. Can I get a visa on arrival on the basis of permit card? Note that I have a one-month Schengen visa as well. What if I travel to Georgia after expiry of the Schengen visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used their eVisa portal and selected your Nationality and Residence Permit and selected Tourism as the purpose and was told that

> **You are exempt from visa!**
>
> Holders of valid visa or residence permit of the country you have selected are exempted from visa requirements. You can enter Georgia without a visa for 90 days in any 180-day period. Please, note that you must present relevant valid visa or residence permit along with your travel document/passport at the moment of crossing Georgian border. Detailed information on visa free travel is available on the following website:
> https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/en/visaInformation

Source: [evisa.gov.ge](https://www.evisa.gov.ge)